# Decoding the xml to html content from t sql xml column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Earlier,In TSQL we have an XML column to store the html data with xml serialization.
But now we think to keep the html content in CDATA region. 
How can I convert the existing xml serialized content to the corresponding html content?

```
e.g. XML serialized column data : <Node Txt="&lt;b&gt;bold text&lt;/b&gt;" />
Expected corresponding transform : <Node><![CDATA[<b>bold text</b>]]></Node>
```

The above transformation is expected to be carried over by sql script.

I think of a solution to replace all those 5 xml special chars corresponding replacement characters (&,<,>,",etc.). But I dont think string manipulation may work in xml to html transformation.

Any cleaner way or idea to transform those existing xml to html data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the PHP function [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to translate it.  If it's a one time thing, this shouldn't be too much trouble for you.

If not, you could code something up using SQL string functions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: But I am expecting this task to be done by sql scripts. This is gonna be a datafix! More over, xml serialized data also contains '&#xA;'